# SpeechToText java Synthesizer is returning NULL

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech-synthesis

I am writing a **Speech-To-Text** program in Java Swing. While trying to start the synthesizer, i am receiving **null**. I have tried many ways and searched a lot but the last line s returning **NULL**

```
String voiceName;
SynthesizerModeDesc desc;
Synthesizer synthesizer;

voiceName = new String("kevin16");

desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(
null, // engine name
"general", // mode name
Locale.US, // locale
null, // running
null); // voice

synthesizer = Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
```

The synthesizer is not initializing.

> This has been solved by using the latest version of synthesizer. Thank
>   you all for your help.

Comment: What does **Central.createSynthesizer(desc)** do? where is the code?

Comment: @MehrajMalik the Central.createSynthesizer(desc) creates the synthesizer with the properties of the array desc. But the systhesizer is returniing a null. that means the systhesizer is not beig created.

Comment: tried debugging it?

Comment: yup.. many times. There is not a single error in the code. Just the synthesizer is not being created

Comment: Have you any implementation of the interface `Synthesizer` in your class path?

Comment: Here is the code i have [link](http://pastebin.com/WS3wvAXm) ... I have also implemented the 'Synthesizer' there

Comment: @Krease  please check the file

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy yes i have. Please check the code

Comment: Use `Central.availableSynthesizers(null)` to get a list of all available syntesizers. If there is none, well, you'll get none.

Comment: @ammoQ it shows there isno synthesizers available. What should i have to do now?

Comment: @suzan Have you installed a synthesizer? If not, you might want to start with downloading and installing FreeTTS  http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php

Comment: @ammoQ yes.. i have jsapi.jar which is supposed to have the synthesizer

Comment: The API is just that, but it is not the synthesizer. It's like JDBC and database.

Comment: SOlved the problem :)